# The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

Hello I have a model `deals.py` as follows:

```
class deals(models.Model):

    GENDER_NAME = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Others'),
        ('A', 'All'),
    )

    AGE_RANGE = (
        ('A1', '18-25'),
        ('A2', '25-40'),
        ('A3', '40-55'),
        ('A4', '55-100'),
        ('A5', '18-100'),
        ('AL', '13-100'),
        ('T1', '13-18')
    )

    store = models.ForeignKey(storesModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='deals_store')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(categoriesModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    targeted_gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_NAME)
    targeted_age = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=AGE_RANGE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiry_date = models.DateField(default=dt(2019, 9, 2, 11, 51, 50, 959364))
```

I have a django rest seralizer as follows:

```
class StoreActiveDealsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = dealsModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

In my view am trying to return a paginated response:

```
data = dealsModel.objects.filter(store=storeid)
paginator = LimitOffsetPagination()
data = paginator.paginate_queryset(data, request),
print(type(data))
serializer = StoreActiveDealsSerializer(data, many=True)
print(type(serializer.data))
return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

However am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `title` on serializer `StoreActiveDealsSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'.

If i try a simple JsonResponse it works:

```
deals = dealsModel.objects.filter(store=storeid)
serializer = StoreActiveDealsSerializer(deals, many=True)
return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

How do i implement the pagination in this?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake:

```
data = paginator.paginate_queryset(data, request),
```

There was a comma **,** at the end of `data = paginator.paginate_queryset(data, request)`